# Iterate a map in JavaScript send from servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate a map in javascript which is sent from backend controller.
I want to make a JSON object based on the value of from the map

the code is like

on my jsp, I'm assigning the value to a hidden variable

```
<input type="hidden" value="${financeGuid }" id="financeGuidList" />
```

now in my javascript, I'm using the above variable as

```
 var financeGuidList = $('#financeGuidList').val();
```

when I try to alert the value of `financeGuidList` it shows like

```
{Acc1=a7efe850-0a5e-4c74-ba7c-2305f3a22ca7, Acc3=554d01fa-9e1e-4d5a-b445-549ceec26bea, Acc9=9c7319eb-0d08-4df8-abba-5c335ac181fd}
```

I used two approaches but none of them worked
1. $.each method
2. for(var a in financeGuidList)

Both results are the same and just produced a long list of 138 key-value pairs

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: That's not a json, it's a hashmap sent from controller. I want to use the value of the key's to built a json

Comment: Well the best thing to do would be to use a JSON encoder in the JSP so that it's already valid JSON when the JavaScript code sees it.